# How to access data in dictionary within list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently working on a python program to query public github API url to get github user email address. The response from the python object is a huge list with a lot of dictionaries.

My code so far

```
import requests
import json

# username = ''

username = 'FamousBern'
base_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/{}/events/public'
url = base_url.format(username)

try:
    res = requests.get(url)
    r = json.loads(res.text)

    # print(r) # List slicing

    print(type(r)) # List that has alot dictionaries

    for i in r:
        if 'payload' in i:
            print(i['payload'][6])


    

    # matches = []
    # for match in r:
    #     if 'author' in match:
    #         matches.append(match)

    # print(matches)
    # print(r[18:])

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
# data = res.json()

# print(data)

# print(type(data))

# email = data['author']

# print(email)
```

By manually accessing this url in chrome browser i get the following

```
[
  {
    "id": "15069094667",
    "type": "PushEvent",
    "actor": {
      "id": 32365949,
      "login": "FamousBern",
      "display_login": "FamousBern",
      "gravatar_id": "",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/users/FamousBern",
      "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/32365949?"
    },
    "repo": {
      "id": 332684394,
      "name": "FamousBern/FamousBern",
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/FamousBern/FamousBern"
    },
    "payload": {
      "push_id": 6475329882,
      "size": 1,
      "distinct_size": 1,
      "ref": "refs/heads/main",
      "head": "f9c165226201c19fd6a6acd34f4ecb7a151f74b3",
      "before": "8b1a9ac283ba41391fbf1168937e70c2c8590a79",
      "commits": [
        {
          "sha": "f9c165226201c19fd6a6acd34f4ecb7a151f74b3",
          "author": {
            "email": "bernardberbell@gmail.com",
            "name": "FamousBern"
          },
          "message": "Changed input functionality",
          "distinct": true,
          "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/FamousBern/FamousBern/commits/f9c165226201c19fd6a6acd34f4ecb7a151f74b3"
        }
      ]
    },
```

The json object is huge as well, i just sliced it. I am interested to get the email address in the author dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to index into a `dict()` with `i['payload'][6]` which will raise an error.

My personal preferred way of checking for key membership in nested `dict`s is using the `get` method with a default of an empty `dict`.

```
import requests
import json

username = 'FamousBern'
base_url = 'https://api.github.com/users/{}/events/public'
url = base_url.format(username)

res = requests.get(url)
r = json.loads(res.text)
# for each dict in the list
for event in r:
    # using .get() means you can chain .get()s for nested dicts 
    # and they won't fail even if the key doesn't exist
    commits = event.get('payload', dict()).get('commits', list())
    # also using .get() with an empty list default means
    # you can always iterate over commits
    for commit in commits:
        # email = commit.get('author', dict()).get('email', None)
        # is also an option if you're not sure if those keys will exist
        email = commit['author']['email']
        print(email)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I will proceed and add regex to just query email address only.